# How to Call and Run a Function of Page A in/from Page B

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to call and run a function in a page, lets say `a.html` from page `b.html`

page `a.html` is like below which has a function to update page background color

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page A</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is Page A</h1>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script>
function UpdatePageA(){
   $("body").css("background-color","gold");
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Page `b.html` is like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page B</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Update Page A from Here</h1>
<button type="button" class="btn update-page-a">Update Page A</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script>

$(".update-page-a").on("click", function(){
   UpdatePageA();
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want that when you press the button `.update-page-a`, it will change the appearance of page A? Or do you just want to reuse that function `UpdatePageA()` to change the background color of `body` in page B?

Comment: Hi, the first part actually. I want to update page A from page B

Answer (score 0):

Option number 4 here: https://blog.bitsrc.io/4-ways-to-communicate-across-browser-tabs-in-realtime-e4f5f6cbedca

This is assuming that you have both tabs open.  If you are talking about sequentially moving from a.html to b.html, then you could use query string parameters or local storage.

Comment: Please note this part: `So this approach only for Browser Tabs opened via window.open() or document.open()`